# I can't set my Manager group as my primary group in substitution to ksapsapkota in linux? When I try to delete the Manager it shows it is the primary

Tags: linux, ubuntu, virtualbox, window, microsoft-teams

I can't set my Manager group as my primary group in substitution to ksapsapkota in Linux. When I try to delete the Manager it shows it is the primary group. I don't know. Is it an error?